# How to sort a datatable in dataset schema

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I am trying to sort a datatable into a Dataset.
In this dataset, I have 2 tables with relationship

> Table 1 - Aluno (student)
>   Table 2 - Curso (course)

The table aluno have a primary key 'CPF'. But I want to sort by NAME (NOME), but the sort sub doesn't work for the parent table ALUNO by NOME.

The result remains unsorted. I do not want to use a dataview as I must order by NAME the Table Student, this table is into a dataset schema.

Here is my code snippet:

```
        if (dtGrdAlunos.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).Row == -1 && dtGrdAlunos.DataSource != null)
        {

            if (sSortType == string.Empty && sColumnToSort == string.Empty)
                sSortType = " ASC";
            else if (sColumnToSort == dtTblAluno.Columns[dtGrdAlunos.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).Column].ColumnName.ToString())
                sSortType = (sSortType == " DESC" ? " ASC" : " DESC");
            else if (sColumnToSort != dtTblAluno.Columns[dtGrdAlunos.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).Column].ColumnName.ToString())
                sSortType = " ASC";

            sColumnToSort = dtTblAluno.Columns[dtGrdAlunos.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).Column].ColumnName.ToString();
            rcTxtLeiaute.Text = sColumnToSort + " " + sSortType;

            dtGrdAlunos.DataSource = null;

            dsDataSet.Tables["Aluno"].DefaultView.Sort = sColumnToSort + sSortType;
            dsDataSet.Tables["Aluno"].AcceptChanges();
            dsDataSet.AcceptChanges();

            dtGrdAlunos.DataSource = dsDataSet.Tables["Aluno"];

            /*
            Application.DoEvents();
            for (int j = 0; j < dsDataSet.Tables["Aluno"].Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                rcTxtLeiaute.Text += j.ToString() + " - " + dsDataSet.Tables["Aluno"].Rows[j]["NOME"].ToString() + "\r";
            }
            */
        }
```

Comment: You don't sort DataTable. You sort data views https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and sort the contents of a data table directly by calling a table's Select method. This strategy allows you to filter and sort only at run time. If you want to set up criteria for filtering and sorting at design time, and especially if you want to bind controls to the results of filtering or sorting, use a data view. For more information, see Filtering and Sorting Data Using Data Views.

[For more details on this click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Actually, with `DataTable.Select` you don't sort your table. You create subset of rows sorted in the order you need. This is completely different from sorting